# Vapor 3 receiving stringified JSON that contains a BOOL

Tags: javascript, json, swift, vapor

I have a webpage that is sending the following JS Object via Ajax to a Vapor handler. The JS object has a Bool variable, as does the receiving struct in Vapor.

When I stringify the JS Object to create a JSON then it Stringifies the true to "true". The Vapor app crashes because it is expecting a bool. The JS object also has am array.

How can I send a JSON that contains non string elements such as Bool or numbers that then can be mapped to a Struct with the same data type?

Comment: Please include the JavaScript code where you create and stringify the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi so just using the console in chrome I knocked together this code which creates the desired effect.

```
 JSON.stringify({ noStr: true }) // "{"noStr":true}"
```

So achieving the string this way should work but if you are using a library like Axios or jQuery this should happen automatically. Perhaps you could share a sample of what you are trying to do and how you are getting a "true" in your request object.

Good luck!